# What is the purpose of using secondaryProgressTint in Seekbar?

Tags: android

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="200"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressTint="#f00"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="#ffff00"/>
```

[image]

I see that `SeekBar` support `secondaryProgressTint` but after I set this, it don't affect anything (after testing on Pixel 4XL and Samsung J7).
Does this property have effect on some device or by some action steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

secondaryProgressTint defines color for secondary progress in android seekbar.

for example

[image]

Find more from the ProgressBar documentation listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:secondaryProgress.

In `ProgressBar` to show secondary progress, first define color for secondary progress by setting secondaryProgressTint attribute to the desired color.

```
<item name="android:secondaryProgressTint">#ffad00</item>
```

Then secondary secondaryProgress with secondary progress value using `setSecondaryProgress(50);`.

Then progress bar will be shown like this:

[image]

Comment: it's interesting. thank you Saitama. Also, is possible for user to change the secondaryProgress on *default* Seekbar from UI (I didn't know it yet but something like long press, double taps, or ...)